# Update JSON based on condition using jq

Tags: json, jq

Supposing that I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "tom",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to specify a package by name, find the corresponding entry in either `dependencies` or `devDependencies` and update the value.

The closest I got was this:

```
$ jq --arg p webpack --arg v 1.2.3 'to_entries | map(
   if (.value[$p]? | startswith("^")?) then 
      .value[$p] = $v
   else . 
   end
) | from_entries' file.json
```

Which updates the value but also removes the `dependencies` and the `name` property:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --progress --colors --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "1.2.3"
  }
}
```

How can I update the desired value without affecting the other properties in the original JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$ jq --arg p webpack --arg v 1.2.3 '
def update_package($package; $version):
    if has($package) then .[$package] = $version
    else . end;
.dependencies |= update_package($p; $v)
    | .devDependencies |= update_package($p; $v)' project.json
```

`update_package/2` will only update the dependency object if it actually references the given project, otherwise it is left alone.  Apply to both `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

The problem with your original filter that was removing the `dependencies` object was that since the project didn't exist, there was no corresponding value to update. By applying `startswith` on the nonexistent value, it caused an error. That error in turn was just ignored and effectively skipped the corresponding item in the map, thus losing that property.

For a quick fix to ensure this doesn't happen, don't ignore the error, provide an alternate value to use when the property doesn't exist.

```
.value[$p]?      | startswith("^")? # bad
.value[$p] // "" | startswith("^")  # better
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. Is there a way to call the function in a loop? I was trying to adapt your code to use `foreach [.dependencies, .devDependencies]` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: You could do this: `.["dependencies","devDependencies"] |= update_package($p; $v)`

Comment: or even `(.dependencies,.devDependencies) |= update_package($p; $v)`

Comment: I decided to "inline" the function in the end `(.dependencies,.devDependencies) |= if has($p) then .[$p] = $v else . end`.

Answer (score 1):

Using your approach, it would be better to use map_values:

```
map_values(if type == "object" 
           then with_entries( if .key == $p and (.value | startswith("^")?) 
                              then .value = $v else . end )
           else . end)
```

You might also like to consider using `walk/1`:

```
walk(if type == "object" and has($p) and (.[$p]|startswith("^"))
     then .[$p] = $v else . end)
```

The solution using `walk/1` will examine the JSON entity recursively.  If your jq does not have `walk`, its definition in jq can readily be found by googling.

#### Robust solution using when/2

```
def when(p;q): if p//false then q else . end;

map_values( when(type == "object";
                 with_entries( when( .key == $p and (.value | startswith("^")?);
                                     .value = $v) )) )
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid my example was over-simplified - there are other properties in the file which cause this approach to fail. I've edited my question to add a property with a string value.

Comment: The answer using map_values has been modified in accordance with the modified question; the answer using walk does not need to be modified, though of course it can be made more robust.

Comment: I think I was over-complicating things by trying to traverse the object when really I knew that the change needed to be made in one of two places. Where does the convention of adding `/N` to the name of functions come from?

Comment: The name/arity notation has been used for a long time in Prolog and Erlang, and more recently in Elixir and no doubt others.